# Can someone enlighten me on what is "Neglected Nonlinearity"?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, terminology, assumptions, nonlinear

I ask this question out of curiosity

earlier today when i was trying to test for heteroscedasticity in `R`, i accidentally mistook `white.test` of `tseries` package for `white.test` of `bstat` package.

i found out later that the former tests for **Neglected Non Linearity** while the latter tests for **Heteroscedasticity**

now this is something new, i hadn't heard about the ***"neglected"*** part before, can someone please enlighten me about the ***"neglected"***?

Comment: One starting point - the paper mentioned in the help for that function is [here](http://dss.ucsd.edu/~hwhite/pub_files/hwcv-041.pdf). The paper defines the term on its second page (p270). Someone who knows the stuff better than me should probably write an answer though.

Comment: Presumabbly it is when you use a linear model when the underlying process is not linear

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments by Henry:

> Presumably it is when you use a linear model when the underlying
> process is not linear